# using a Struct to change tableViewCell from TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift

In my app's chat feature, I use a `UITableView` to present chat history.

Cells are subclasses of `UITableViewCell`. The class receives a Chat object that contains all the info it needs to build the cell.

I have a Firebase listener that fires when the "last message" is changed. It changes a UILabel text to "new Message!" and then a protocol/delegate reloads the table view. Now I need to change the label back to "".

When the user clicks the cell, I use didSelectRowAt to segue to JSQMessagesViewController after preparing for segue. My idea is to use prepare for segue or even didSelectRowAt itself to change a Boolean variable in the UITableViewCell that corresponds to that chat Object. Navigating back to the tableViewController will trigger reloadData.

Each ChatObject has a unique ID that I can access. After firing the listener, I will set this Boolean to one value. After clicking the cell, I will set it to another. the state of the variable will tell the IBOutlet what text to show. In the UITableViewCell class, I use:

```
    var chat: Chat! {
    didSet {
        self.updateUI()
        }
    }
}
```

So in `self.updateUI()` I make necessary changes, but can I make properties in the `UITableViewCell` mutable/visible from the `UITableViewController`?

Comment: What does this have to do with "using a Struct"? And what's the actual question? I can't even find it. What's the _problem_? Show code that demonstrates it, please. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make properties in the UITableViewCell that are mutable from the UITableViewController

You don't. You make changes in your *model* and tell the table view to reload its data.

Comment: Do you think I'm giving the cell too much responsibility by giving it an object and putting it in charge of displaying data from the object?

Comment: Absolutely. Cells  are view, not model; they must never hold data. Even more important, they are constantly jumping around within the table as they are reused in different rows, so they must constantly change the data they display to reflect their use in a different row. The model is where the data live; `cellForRowAt:` makes the visible cells correspond to the model data, that's what it's for.

Comment: ok, so, I should add a variable to my chat class that will say "New Message"  or "" (Model).  these should be changed with listeners in the TableViewController itself (Controller) When reloadData() is called, the Cell will have all the updated data it needs (View). am I on the right track?

Comment: Hey, with the constant mantra of MVC I accomplished what I intended. Thank you for turning me on to the correct mindset.

Answer (score 0):

> So in self.updateUI() I make necessary changes, but can I make properties in the UITableViewCell mutable from the UITableViewController?

I don't think you're trying to do what you say you are. In the case that you are trying to access the properties of your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, you might want to use `cellForRowAtIndexPath()`. Then cast the result to whatever class name you have for your `UITableViewCell` subclass.

**Example**:
If I want to change the 5th row outside of our table view `dataSource`, I could do something like this.

```
 let fifthIndexPath = IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0)
 let thisCell = myTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(at indexPath: fifthIndexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell
 thisCell.property = value
```

See:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview